# Android Studio 3.4.2 URI Configuration

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.4

I'm creating my first app in android studio 3.4.2, when the code displays I'm getting error message like "URI is not registered".

When the code displays, it was underlined and saying

> URI is not registerd

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

The code should generate the output "Hello World"

[image]

Comment: Something is borked with your dev environment. without further info I don't think this question can be answered... I would try reinstalling the android sdk

Comment: I'm new to this can you please guide me with the installation process?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/android/ug/install-android-sdk-platform-packages-and-sdk-tools.html